# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value error with parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve user profile image from parse. I have a collection view and I am retrieving all images people posted. I want to show each users profile image in the cell as well. I was using the below code

```
 let query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{(question:[AnyObject]?,error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil
        {
            if let allQuestion = question as? [PFObject]
            {
                self.votes = allQuestion
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

and

```
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("newview", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewCollectionViewCell
    let item = self.votes[indexPath.row]

    var UserQuery:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
    if let user = PFUser.currentUser() {
        UserQuery.whereKey("uploader", equalTo: user)
    }
    UserQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?)->Void in
        if error == nil{

            let user:PFUser = (objects as NSArray!).lastObject as! PFUser
            cell.userName!.text = user.username

            let PhotoFile:PFFile = user["profilePicture"] as! PFFile
            PhotoFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock(){
                (ImageData:NSData?, error:NSError?)->Void in
                if error == nil{
                    let Image:UIImage = UIImage(data: ImageData!)!
                    cell.profileImageView.image = Image
                }}}}
```

However I get an error saying fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value at                 `let user:PFUser = (objects as NSArray!).lastObject as! PFUser`

[image]

The problem is, I can't retrieve the profile image and name for this specific user from the pointer that I have created. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I get an error saying fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value at
>
> ```
> let user:PFUser = (objects as NSArray!).lastObject as! PFUser
> ```

So don't say that. Any time you use the exclamation mark like that, you are asking to crash if it fails. And that's what's happening. So don't use the exclamation mark. Use the question mark, like this:

```
 if let user = (objects as? NSArray)?.lastObject as? PFUser {
      // ...
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, that code won't work for me. error saying value of optional type PFUser? not unwrapped did you mean to use ! or?

Comment: Okay, I can't test it because I don't use Parse, but you can fix it up. I mean, surely you get the idea of what I'm suggesting here.

Comment: yes I get what you mean, but want to know from a user who uses parse if my method is correct when retrieving the image from a user pointer.

Comment: Also why are you turning this array back into an NSArray? Isn't that sort of silly?

Comment: ok I think I messed things up I just want to retrieve the picture from the pointer